# Как интегрировать php код в плагин для wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Первый раз делаю плагин для wordpress. Пока на начальном этапе, но надо уже интегрировать код на страницу как плагин, как это можно сделать? Как подготовить страницу к этому(там только выбор дизайна и прочее). Суть кода определить занятость домена. Вот код, как можно сделать плагином, что нужно писать или добавить? Помимо этой части

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Название плагина
Plugin URI: http://страница_с_описанием_плагина_и_его_обновлений
Description: Краткое описание плагина.
Version: Номер версии плагина, например: 1.0
Author: Имя автора плагина
Author URI: http://страница_автора_плагина
*/
?>
```

Вот сам код на php <?php

```
function check_domain()
{
    $host = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name']));
    $json = file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/' . $host . '?lang=ru');
    $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    if (strcasecmp($array['status'], 'fail') == 0)
        echo "<h5>Домен"."  ".$host."  "."свободен</h5>";
    else
        echo "<h5>Домен"."  ".$host."  "."зарегистрирован</h5>";

}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2><center>Проверка домена на занятость</center</h2>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <label for="name">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="введите Домен">
    <input type="submit" value="отправить">
    </label>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty(trim($_POST['name']))) {
    check_domain();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот полный код плагина с комментариями. Код протестирован.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Название плагина
 * Plugin URI: http://страница_с_описанием_плагина_и_его_обновлений
 * Description: Краткое описание плагина.
 * Version: Номер версии плагина, например: 1.0
 * Author: Имя автора плагина
 * Author URI: http://страница_автора_плагина
 */

/**
 * Check domain.
 *
 * @param string $domain_name Domain name.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function check_domain( $domain_name ) {
    $host  = htmlspecialchars( trim( $domain_name ) );
    $json  = file_get_contents( 'http://ip-api.com/json/' . $host . '?lang=ru' );
    $array = json_decode( $json, true );

    if ( strcasecmp( $array['status'], 'fail' ) === 0 ) {
        return '<h5>Домен ' . $host . ' свободен</h5>';
    }

    return '<h5>Домен ' . $host . ' зарегистрирован</h5>';
}

/**
 * Domain shortcode.
 *
 * @return false|string
 */
function check_domain_shortcode() {
    // We have to return string, so wrap html into output buffer functions.
    ob_start();

    ?>
    <h2>Проверка домена на занятость</h2>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="domain_name">
            <input type="text" name="domain_name" placeholder="Введите домен">
            <input type="submit" value="отправить">
        </label>
    </form>
    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'check_domain', 'check_domain_shortcode' );

/**
 * Process domain page.
 *
 * @param string $content Post content.
 *
 * @return mixed|string
 */
function domain_page( $content ) {
    if ( has_shortcode( $content, 'check_domain' ) ) {
        // Do not use 'name' POST var in WordPress. It is reserved.
        if ( isset( $_POST['domain_name'] ) ) {
            $domain_name = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'domain_name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

            // Add the result of checking below the form.
            return $content . check_domain( $domain_name );
        }
    }

    return $content;
}

// Add processing of the content. Priority 0 to work before conversion of shortcodes.
add_action( 'the_content', 'domain_page', 0 );
```

Активируйте плагин и добавьте на страницу или в пост шорткод `[check_domain]`. Шорткод выведет форму, а код по хуку `the_content` - проверит статус домена и добавит результат ниже формы.

Comment: Здравствуйте, а зачем мы создали функцию check_domain_shortcode?

Comment: Эта функция реализует шорткод. Она срабатывает, когда в контенте страницы или поста ядро WordPress встречает `[check_domain]`. Тогда, для замены этого шорткода при выводе на экран, вызывается `check_domain_shortcode`. Это стандартный механизм ядра: https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/codex/shortcodes

Comment: А такой вопрос. Если я хочу добавить новый функционал в плагин(например черный список), который можно будет редактировать с помощью панели администрирования, для этого мне нужно сначала добавить в php файл массив со списком запрещенных доменов?

Comment: Вам надо сделать страницу настроек в админке. Сделать можно по-разному. Есть совсем простые рецепты. Есть статьи о том, как правильно: https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html